# Principal Part and little o notation

Tags: limits

The function is $f(x) = 2x + e^{x+x^{4/3}} -1$ and the question wants the principal part with respect to $g(x)=x$ as $x$ goes to $0^+$.

I solved it using MacLaurin expansion and I got $3x$, but should it also have the little $o$ notation with the answer, like $3x + o(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

As $x\to 0^+$,
$$e^{x+x^{4/3}}=1+(x+x^{4/3})+O(x^2)=1+x+O(x^{4/3}).$$
with [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Therefore you may write
$$f(x)=3x+O(x^{4/3})\quad\mbox{or}\quad f(x)=3x+o(x^{a})$$
with any $1\leq a<4/3$.